# Legendre symbol of $\left(\!\frac{11}{71}\!\right)$

Tags: number-theory

I'm trying to find the Legendre symbol of 
$\left(\!\frac{11}{71}\!\right)$ .

Here is what I did so far :

$$\left(\!\frac{11}{71}\!\right)=(-1)^{{((11-1)/2}⋅{(71-1)/2)}}⋅\left(\!\frac{71}{11}\!\right)=(-1)^{5} (-1)^{35} \left(\!\frac{71}{11}\!\right)$$

$$\left(\!\frac{11}{71}\!\right)= 71^{((11-1)/2)} \pmod{11}=71^5 \pmod{11} = ?$$

How can I continue from here ?

Thanks

Comment: What is the remainder when you divide $71$ by $11$?

Comment: As Daniel suggests, you can reduce 71 mod 11.

Comment: Also be carefull : $(-1)^{ab} \neq (-1)^a.(-1)^b$

Comment: Note that $\left(\!\frac{11}{71}\!\right)$ is converted to a power of $-1$ times $\left(\!\frac{71}{11}\!\right)$ and the Legendre symbol is the same as $\left(\!\frac{5}{11}\!\right)$. Then (if necessary) note that $\left(\!\frac{5}{11}\!\right)$ is a power of $-1$ times $\left(\!\frac{11}{5}\!\right)=\left(\!\frac{1}{5}\!\right)=1.$ Quadratic reciprocity gives you the powers and hence the sign you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first attempt, as noted in the comments, you have an error: $(-1)^{ab}\ne(-1)^a(-1)^b$.

For both attempts, also as noted in the comments, to continue further reduce $71$ mod $11$.

Here is a different example to get an idea with:

$$\left(\frac{13}{59}\right)=(-1)^{6\cdot29}\left(\frac{59}{13}\right)=\left(\frac{7}{13}\right)=(-1)^{3\cdot6}\left(\frac{13}{7}\right)=\left(\frac{-1}{7}\right)=(-1)^{3}. $$

Comment: Exactly. Computing Legendre symbols can be done systematically this way: 1) make the numerator odd (possibly negative) 2) Factor out the $-1$ (if present) and deal with it using Euler's criterion. 3) Split the Legendre symbol by factoring the numerator in prime powers. (Disregard the ones with even exponent.) 4) Apply reciprocity to all factors. 5) Repeat the procedure (during which the denominators decrease strictly every step) until all denominators are $3$, at which point Euler's criterion can be used again (the numerator will be $\pm1$).

Answer (score 2):

You use the law of quadratic reciprocity which says that

$$\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)=\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)$$ except when both $p$ and $q$ are $\equiv 3\pmod 4$ in which case 
$$\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)=-\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)$$

So 
$$\left(\frac{11}{71}\right)=-\left(\frac{71}{11}\right)=-\left(\frac{5}{11}\right)=
-\left(\frac{11}{5}\right)=-\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)=-1$$

Where we note that $$11,71 \equiv 3 \pmod 4$$ and $$5 \equiv 1 \pmod 4$$

Comment: The computation is clearly correct, but when one reaches $\left(\frac5{11}\right)$ it could be noted at a glance that $5\equiv16=4^2\bmod11$ obtaining the result immediately.

Answer (score 2):

Although $71^5 = 1804229351$ is technically a small number by the frivolous theorem of arithmetic, it can still be daunting, especially if you don't have a computer or at least a calculator.

But what you can do is go through the exponents modulo $11$ from the get-go. Thus:

- $71 \equiv 5 \pmod{11}$
- $71^2 \equiv 5^2 \equiv 3 \pmod{11}$
- $71^3 \equiv 3 \times 5 \equiv 4 \pmod{11}$
- $71^4 \equiv 4 \times 5 \equiv 9 \pmod{11}$
- $71^5 \equiv 9 \times 5 \equiv 1 \pmod{11}$

Therefore $$\left(\frac{11}{71}\right) = 1.$$

P.S. In case of the opposite answer, depending on how you went about it, you might see $10$ rather than $-1$. It still means the same thing.